# How to make it a one to one relationship

Tags: database, ms-access, data-modeling, erd

I am designing a data model and i am having a problem creating an invoice correctly. I would like to make my invoice to booking table as 1:1 and to be able to create invoice number when filling out the booking table. I seem to be unable to do this even when trying a combination key. Anyone have any suggestions as to why it may not be working for me. Any help is much appreciated

[image: Data model]

Answer (score 1):

If your data model really is only one invoice per booking then simply add the invoice number and invoice date into your booking table.

You are making your life difficult for no obvious reason.

Answer (score 0):

When you have compound primary key (Invoice), you must join on all the fields of the key or you can't update.

Comment: ive connected both keys and it says one to one relationship but when i try to create the booking it says a relate record is required in the invoice table. I want to be able to create the invoice in the booking

Comment: Only BookingID seems joined.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Field Property for Invoice Number and/or Booking ID has the Indexed value set to "Yes (No Duplicates)" in the Table Design View

Also if there is only ever going to be one Invoice Number per Booking, then you should have no reason to include the BookingID in the Invoice Table.

Comment: I have changed that there and now it is one to one but it still making me create an invoice number through the invoice table instead of through the booking table

Comment: That's how it should be, you shouldn't be creating a Unique ID for a row in another table. Actually that is quite frankly not possible. After the Invoice is created in that table, you should retrieve that value and assign it into the field in your Booking Table.